# JavaScript - Display a bar graph with dictionary in ECharts

Tags: javascript, django, graph, protocols, echarts

is there a way to display a bar graph with given source dataset in one dictionary? I'm using ECharts and it's hard to understand their documentation :(

My data:

```
{"TCP": 1003, "UDP": 232, "ICMP": 4, "IP": 0}
```

And my option is right there:

```
var option = {
                dataset: {
                    source : myChart
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Protocol'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    data: ['TCP', 'UDP', 'ICMP', 'IP']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    data: [0, 100, 300, 500, 700, 900, 1100]
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Protocol',
                    type: 'bar',
                }]
            };
```

Thanks a lot for any advice !

@EDIT
So the problem is in my JavaScript code... I can't access values, what's the problem ?

```
const proto = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('proto').textContent);
            console.log(proto);
            console.log(proto['IP']);
```

I forgot to mention proto element is from django variable

```
{{ proto|json_script:"proto" }}
```

@EDIT2
Only working is to put a variable with safe tag, is it okay? Or may it be vulnerable to xss?

```
var proto = JSON.parse('{{ proto|safe }}');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the simple example and replace data: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-background

Comment: Thanks for an example, but i checked that my problem is in javascript code :( Maybe by any chance you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Maybe you better integrate [pyecharts](https://pyecharts.org/) into you system? [Here](https://pyecharts.org/#/en-us/django) you can find detail tutorial.